# Property 'actions' does not exist on type 'typeof Office' When using Word task pane add-in

Tags: javascript, reactjs, office-addins

I was tasked to adding an additional feature to our Word Addin.

We are trying to add custom shortcuts.

I have used the code that was given on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/keyboard-shortcuts#configure-the-manifest and when using the code I get the error: Property 'actions' does not exist on type 'typeof Office'

Here is what the code looks like:

```
Office.actions.associate('SHOWTASKPANE', function () {
    return Office.addin.showAsTaskpane()
        .then(function () {
            return;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            return error.code;
        });
});
```

I have gone through the Office.js file and I cant see if anything is missing.

Your help would really be appreciated

Comment: I am facing a similar issue with the Office class type. Did you figure out how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

May add these functions to the global scope and don`t use action will help for you.

```
function getGlobal() {
  return typeof self !== "undefined"
? self
: typeof window !== "undefined"
? window
: typeof global !== "undefined"
? global
: undefined;
}

let g = getGlobal()

g.SHOWTASKPANE= function () {
    return Office.addin.showAsTaskpane()
        .then(function () {
            return;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            return error.code;
        });
});;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
npm install @types/office-js --save-dev
```